# How do I customize the behavior of "cut" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

My normal IDE is Visual Studio, but I'm currently doing some development in Eclipse for the first time.  If you press Ctrl-X with text selected in either program, it cuts the text and puts on the clipboard exactly as you'd expect.  If press Ctrl-X with no text selected in Visual Studio, it cuts the current line.  In Eclipse it is ignored.  Is there a way to get Eclipse to use Studio's behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/copycutcurrentline/

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a way to make Ctrl+X context sensitive, but I did find that you can bind a key to the "Cut Line" command by going to the Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys dialog.  Unfortunately this always cuts the entire line, even when you have only part of it selected.  Maybe binding another key to this command will work for you?